# Trying to use pdepe function to solve spherical diffusion equation

Tags: matlab, pde

I need to solve the spherical pde diffusion equation:

dq/dt=(1/r^2)*d/dr(r^2*D*(dq/dr))

D is a constant

initial condition is q=0 at t=0

boundary conditions are: dq/dr=0 at r=0, q=1 at r=Rc

I have written the following code but I am getting an error:

```
function pde1
m=2;
x=linspace(0.01,1,20);
t=linspace(0.01,2,10);
sol=pdepe(m,@pdefun,@pdeic,@pdebc,x,t);
u=sol(:,:,1);

% A surface plot
surf(x,t,u)
title('Surface plot')
xlabel('Distance x')
ylabel('Time t')
end
%-----------------------------------
function [c,f,s]=pdefun(x,t,u,DuDx)
global d
c=1/d;
f=DuDx;
s=0;
end
%-----------------------------------------------------
function [pl,ql,pr,qr]= pdebc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t)
global r
pl=0;
ql=0;
pr=1;
qr=r;
end
%------------------------------------------------
function u0 = pdeic(x)
u0=0;
end
```

could you please tell me what's wrong with it?

The error is:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in pdefun (line 3)
c=1/d;

Error in pdepe (line 246)
[c,f,s] = feval(pde,xi(1),t(1),U,Ux,varargin{:});

Error in pde1 (line 5)
sol=pdepe(m,@pdefun,@pdeic,@pdebc,x,t);
```

Thanks

Comment: "getting an error" isn't very specific, but off the bat, it looks like you didn't define your conductivity `d0` (or misspelled as `d`).  Additionally, from a math perspective, having a B.C. on the right-hand side of `1` and an initial condition of `0` is inconsistent and may lead to problems.

Comment: Can you expand on the error?

Comment: @TroyHaskin I didn't get what you meant by expanding on conductivity.